# Floats / Margins in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I'm having a weird issue that I appear to only see in Firefox. Chrome and surprisingly IE work just fine. The site that link below works fine in both of these browsers but in firefox the whole page gets pushed to the right while the #spotlightbar get pushed to the left. Im at a loss of what the problem may be. Any suggestions?

http://www.bristolymca.net/index.php

EDIT: So this has been solved. Thanks for the quick help to all.

SOLUTION: Obviously when you you float one div on a page inside of a content block either the rest needs to be floated as well or you need to clear the float before and after what you have floated. This was my mistake in misnaming CSS classes. So for future reference make sure those are the same name!

Comment: Add `clear: both` to #homeHeaderArea and #contentHome

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no styles on

```
<div id="contentHome">
```

Add some css like this;

```
#contentHome {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was indeed the problem. Looks like in my css i some how changed the capitalization. Thanks for the help with the silly question.

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help :) please mark the answer as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, my first suggestion would be to prevent using tables for layout elements and inline styling.

I removed the inline styling and added the following css properties to it:

```
width: 100%;
float: left;
```

That solved the problem to me.

PS: Pretty webpage, congrats!